# Can I use a variable address in an ISBLANK() statement

Tags: vba, excel, variables

I'm trying to add conditional formatting into a vba code and am having trouble with my ISBLANK statement.

Is it possible to use a variable address to define the cell I would like to check?

Here is what I have so far.

```
`Sub Employee_Training_Record()
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim lastcol As Long

If Cells(3, 2).Value = "" Then
MsgBox "No Employees in List"
GoTo gohere1:
ElseIf Cells(2, 3).Value = "" Then
MsgBox "No Training in List"
GoTo gohere1:
End If

lastrow = Cells(30, 2).End(xlUp).Row
lastcol = Cells(2, 30).End(xlToLeft).Column

employee = InputBox("Enter Employee Name")
Do While employee = ""
employee = InputBox("Enter Employee Name")
Loop
For i = 3 To lastrow
    a = 0
    If Cells(i, 2).Value = employee Then
    GoTo gohere:
    Else
    a = 1
    End If
Next
If a = 1 Then
MsgBox "Employee Not Found"
GoTo gohere1:
End If
gohere:

trning = InputBox("Enter Training Type")
Do While trning = ""
trning = InputBox("Enter Training Type")
Loop
For i = 3 To lastcol
    b = 0
    If Cells(2, i).Value = trning Then
    GoTo gohere5:
    Else
    b = 1
    End If
Next
If b = 1 Then
MsgBox "Training Not Found"
GoTo gohere1:
End If
gohere5:

exprnc = InputBox("Enter Expiration Date")
For i = 3 To lastrow
    If Cells(i, 2).Value = employee Then
    GoTo gohere3:
    End If
Next
gohere3:
For j = 1 To lastcol
    If Cells(2, j).Value = trning Then
    j = j + 1
    GoTo gohere4:
    End If
Next
gohere4:

Cells(i, j).Value = exprnc

    Cells(i, j).FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlLess, _
        Formula1:="=NOW()+60"
    Cells(i, j).FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Cells(i, j).FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 49407
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Cells(i, j).FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

    Cells(i, j).FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlLess, _
        Formula1:="=NOW()"
    Cells(i, j).FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 255
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Cells(i, j).FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

    addrss = Cells(i, j).Address

    Cells(i, j).FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=ISBLANK(addrss)=True"
    Cells(i, j).FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    Cells(i, j).FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = True

    MsgBox "Cell Address" & Cells(i, j).Address()

gohere1:
End Sub`
```

Comment: `Formula1:="=ISBLANK(" & addrss & ")=True"`. What ever you put inside `"` is just string literally.

Comment: try `"=ISBLANK(" & addrss & ")=True"`

Comment: Awesome those worked perfectly.  Thank you.